# Difference between Facebook all.js and sdk.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I trying to upgrade an app to the current Facebook API (v2.7), because Facebook warns that our current used API (v2.0) is deprecated. I looked in the code and found the `sdk.js` and changed the version property of the  configuration parameter of the `FB.init` function to `v2.7`.

Then I found other `FB.init` calls, that uses `all.js`. It seems that the `FB.init` function of `all.js` doesn't need the version.

I looked at the Facebook developer page for `all.js`, but I can't find any information about that.

So, what is the difference between `sdk.js` and `all.js`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So, what is the difference between sdk.js and all.js?

all.js is the “old” version of the SDK; when API v2.0 was introduced, they changed that to sdk.js

Forget all.js existed; sdk.js is the only one you should be using.

Comment: you can't find any `all.js` in any official documents.

Comment: It appears that `all.js` is still available to support legacy applications.